# error al añadir filtro en web.xml

Tags: java

Buenas a tod@s,

He añadido un filtro nuevo a mi web.xml en concreto:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>FiltroVulnerabilidad</display-name>
    <filter-name>FiltroVulnerabilidad</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        es.aig.extranet.util.vulnerabilidad.FiltroVulnerabilidad
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FiltroVulnerabilidad</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Y la clase que lo controla:

```
package es.aig.extranet.util.vulnerabilidad;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class FiltroVulnerabilidad implements Filter {

private static Log log;

static {
    log = LogFactory.getFactory().getInstance(FiltroVulnerabilidad.class);
}

/**
 *
 */
public void init(FilterConfig filterconfig) throws ServletException {
}

/**
 *
 */
public void destroy() {
}

/**
 *
 */
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

    String uri = request.getRequestURI();

    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest)req).getSession();

    if(session == null && !(uri.matches("axis2-web"))){
        limpiaSesion(session,(HttpServletRequest)req);
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }else{
        try {

            chain.doFilter(req, resp);

        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param session
 */
private void limpiaSesion(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {

    /* Comprobamos si venimos de una opcion del menu */
    String cleanSession = (String) request.getParameter("cs");
    if(cleanSession!=null && cleanSession.equals("1")){

        String objectName = null;

        /* Lipiamos los formularios de la session */
        for(Enumeration enum1 = session.getAttributeNames(); enum1.hasMoreElements();) {
            objectName = (String)enum1.nextElement();

            if(objectName.endsWith("Form")){
                session.removeAttribute(objectName);
            }
        }
    }

    Object object;
    String objectName;

    for(Enumeration enum1 = session.getAttributeNames(); enum1.hasMoreElements();) {
        objectName = (String)enum1.nextElement();
        object = (Object) session.getAttribute(objectName);
    }
}
```

}

La aplicación esta desarrollada con strut 1 y spring, es una aplicación muy antigua que consta de varias aplicaciones (distintos web.xml, distintos .war) que comparten una misma BBDD y un conjunto de librerías (.jar) de modo que según en que opción de menú pulsemos estaremos yendo a una aplicación u otra (con sus distintos struts-config.xml y action-servlet.xml). Pues bien, en el momento de acceder a la aplicación en concreto cuyo web.xml he modificado sale el siguiente mensaje de error en el log que tengo configurado con log4j:

```
  20-Nov-2017 12:15:03.428 SEVERE [http-nio-9080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Excepción arrancando filtro FiltroVulnerabilidad
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: es.aig.extranet.util.vulnerabilidad.FiltroVulnerabilidad
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1586)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

El filtro lo añadí tomando como ejemplo otros filtros que se que funcionan, lo único que hice fue cambiar la clase controladora (FiltroVulnerabilidad) para la parte java y en el web.xml la parte del código que os adjunté anteriormente.

He realizado búsquedas para ver si hay algún otro fichero de configuración que se me estuviera pasando por alto y sólo he encontrado los distintos web.xml de la distintas aplicaciones (no en todos).

Espero que alguien pueda echarme una mano

un saludo,

Comment: ¿El web.xml con el filtro y la clase que lo implementa están en el mismo WAR? ¿La clase está en un Jar independiente?

Comment: La clase se encuentra en un jar independiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comprueba que el `jar` con el filtro está dentro de la carpeta `WEB-INF/lib` del `war` que contiene el `web.xml` que hace referencia al filtro.

Comment: el .jar no se encuentra en el lib del war solo me aparece el xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar

Comment: Pues ese es el problema, debe ir incluido, o estar en una carpeta a nivel de servidor.

Comment: Algo se me escapa porque en el web.xml hay otros filtros al mismo nivel (paquetes) que el que he metido yo y estos funcionan perfectamente.

Comment: Igual está por ahí el jar a nivel de servidor, pero es una versión anterior, sin la clase FiltroVulnerabilidad.

Comment: voy a meter la clase del filtro en el mismo paquete donde están los demás filtros. Ahora te comento pablo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: problema resuelto! el error estaba en la versión de la librería que estaba desplegando en servidor. Olvidé subir la versión en el pom y estaba desplegando una versión antigua. Muchas gracias a pablo por su ayuda.